# How do I console.log an attribute in a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, jinja2

I am trying to console.log the `'data-id'` attribute however I keep getting `1` in my console when I click on a new `'.dropdown-item'`. This is a snippet of the HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
  {% for date in joined_dates %}
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-id="{{loop.index}}">{{date}}</a>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

This is a snippet of the javascript:

```
d3.json('/data', function(error, closure_data) {
  var btn = d3.selectAll('.dropdown-item')
  btn.forEach(function(value, index) {
    value = btn.attr('data-id')
    btn.on('click', function() {
      d3.select('#text').text('1')
      console.log(value)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: I don't know much about d3js, but I've create a working example with d3js and plain js (bootstrap is just for the dropdown). Can you check it? https://jsfiddle.net/ofyrd4sk/1/

Comment: `d3.selectAll('.dropdown-item').on("click", function() { d3.select('#text').text('1'); console.log(this.dataset.id); })` is all you need.

Comment: Thank you @altocumulus, this works!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @altocumulus, I found a pretty simple solution and here it is:

```
d3.selectAll('.dropdown-item').on("click", function() { d3.select('#text').text('1'); console.log(this.dataset.id); })
```

Explanation to this I guess is that the `data-id` is a subset of `data-` classes and its value can be called upon by using `.dataset.id`. My understanding is we can put almost anything after `data-` when creating the class and still get the same result.

If anyone has a better explanation, please let me know! Thank you!